# Top icons of STS not visible

Tags: spring-tool-suite

My top icons of run, debug search and all icons are not visible
Please have a look
[image: issue-sts.png]

I have also tried discarding this STS and tried another one. Faced same issues. Icons vanish and sometimes STS fails to start.
Another solution was to customize perspective but, when i tried to do that,
1. Window -> Perspective-> Custom Perspective

-- Error Details --

> Date: Thu Dec 29 10:36:52 IST 2016 Message: Unhandled event loop
>   exception Severity: Error Product: Spring Tool Suite
>   3.8.3.201612191351-RELEASE (org.springsource.sts.ide) Plugin: org.eclipse.ui Session Data:
>   eclipse.buildId=3.8.3.201612191351-RELEASE-e46 java.version=1.8.0_51
>   java.vendor=Oracle Corporation BootLoader constants: OS=linux,
>   ARCH=x86_64, WS=gtk, NL=en_IN Framework arguments:  -product
>   org.springsource.sts.ide Command-line arguments:  -os linux -ws gtk
>   -arch x86_64 -product org.springsource.sts.ide -clean

Exception Stack Trace:

`java.lang.StackOverflowError
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Control.setLocation(Control.java:1185)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.widgets.ImageBasedFrame.setFramedControlLocation(ImageBasedFrame.java:124)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.widgets.ImageBasedFrame.access$0(ImageBasedFrame.java:120)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.widgets.ImageBasedFrame$4.controlMoved(ImageBasedFrame.java:109)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.TypedListener.handleEvent(TypedListener.java:225)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.EventTable.sendEvent(EventTable.java:84)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.sendEvent(Display.java:5227)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1340)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1366)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1345)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Control.setBounds(Control.java:1100)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Composite.setBounds(Composite.java:1527)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.ToolBar.setBounds(ToolBar.java:589)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Control.setLocation(Control.java:1187)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.widgets.ImageBasedFrame.setFramedControlLocation(ImageBasedFrame.java:124)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.widgets.ImageBasedFrame.access$0(ImageBasedFrame.java:120)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.widgets.ImageBasedFrame$4.controlMoved(ImageBasedFrame.java:109)
    at ......................`

**

> Update 1 :

**

Following error is seen immediately after I start STS

!SESSION 2017-01-02 09:42:44.171 -----------------------------------------------

> eclipse.buildId=3.8.2.201610040743-RELEASE-e46 java.version=1.8.0_51
>   java.vendor=Oracle Corporation BootLoader constants: OS=linux,
>   ARCH=x86_64, WS=gtk, NL=en_IN Framework arguments:  -product
>   org.springsource.sts.ide Command-line arguments:  -os linux -ws gtk
>   -arch x86_64 -product org.springsource.sts.ide

```
This is a continuation of log file /home/swapnil/Documents/code/workspaces/olabsWorkspace/.metadata/.bak_0.log
Created Time: 2017-01-02 09:44:58.413

!ENTRY org.eclipse.equinox.event 4 0 2017-01-02 09:44:58.414
!MESSAGE Exception while dispatching event org.osgi.service.event.Event [topic=org/eclipse/e4/ui/model/ui/ElementContainer/children/ADD] {ChangedElement=org.eclipse.e4.ui.model.application.ui.basic.impl.TrimBarImpl@65d23aa3 (elementId: org.eclipse.ui.main.toolbar, tags: [], contributorURI: null) (widget: Composite {}, renderer: org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench.renderers.swt.TrimBarRenderer@63bdf82d, toBeRendered: true, onTop: false, visible: true, containerData: null, accessibilityPhrase: null) (side: Top), org.eclipse.e4.data={ChangedElement=org.eclipse.e4.ui.model.application.ui.basic.impl.TrimBarImpl@65d23aa3 (elementId: org.eclipse.ui.main.toolbar, tags: [], contributorURI: null) (widget: Composite {}, renderer: org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench.renderers.swt.TrimBarRenderer@63bdf82d, toBeRendered: true, onTop: false, visible: true, containerData: null, accessibilityPhrase: null) (side: Top), AttName=children, EventType=ADD, Position=11, Widget=Composite {}, NewValue=org.eclipse.e4.ui.model.application.ui.menu.impl.ToolBarImpl@72f9cd3f (elementId: org.eclipse.m2e.editor.MavenPomEditor, tags: [Draggable], contributorURI: null) (widget: ToolBar {}, renderer: org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench.renderers.swt.ToolBarManagerRenderer@79177bc, toBeRendered: true, onTop: false, visible: true, containerData: null, accessibilityPhrase: null)}, AttName=children, EventType=ADD, Position=11, Widget=Composite {}, NewValue=org.eclipse.e4.ui.model.application.ui.menu.impl.ToolBarImpl@72f9cd3f (elementId: org.eclipse.m2e.editor.MavenPomEditor, tags: [Draggable], contributorURI: null) (widget: ToolBar {}, renderer: org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench.renderers.swt.ToolBarManagerRenderer@79177bc, toBeRendered: true, onTop: false, visible: true, containerData: null, accessibilityPhrase: null)} to handler org.eclipse.e4.core.di.internal.extensions.EventObjectSupplier$DIEventHandler@374d3128
!STACK 0

java.lang.StackOverflowError
    at org.eclipse.swt.events.ControlEvent.<init>(ControlEvent.java:35)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.TypedListener.handleEvent(TypedListener.java:225)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.EventTable.sendEvent(EventTable.java:84)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.sendEvent(Display.java:5219)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1340)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1366)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1345)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Control.setBounds(Control.java:1100)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Composite.setBounds(Composite.java:1524)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.ToolBar.setBounds(ToolBar.java:589)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Control.setLocation(Control.java:1187)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.widgets.ImageBasedFrame.setFramedControlLocation(ImageBasedFrame.java:124)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.widgets.ImageBasedFrame.access$0(ImageBasedFrame.java:120)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.widgets.ImageBasedFrame$4.controlMoved(ImageBasedFrame.java:109)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.TypedListener.handleEvent(TypedListener.java:225)
```

Comment: This sounds like something serious is broken. What OS are you running on? Did you try a fresh install of the STS distribution? And do you have steps how to reproduce this and when exactly this happens?

Comment: OS is Linux mint 17 . It's Ubuntu trusty based. I have downloaded sts 2-3 versions and have same output for all of them. I have stackoverflow error on perspective change. Also the UI icons are visible only at first launch. After that no icons are visible.

Comment: Do you see anything in the Error Log view that could be related?

Comment: Hmmm, hard to tell from those errors. But there must be something serious going on. Can you check the latest pure Eclipse IDE to see if that makes a difference?

Comment: Exactly same error in eclipse neon too... with same symptoms.

Comment: In that case I would recommend to file a bug at: https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/enter_bug.cgi?product=Platform. You could also try to run Eclipse with its GTK2 support via SWT_GTK3=0 (as an environment variable), maybe that helps. But as GTK2 support is limited and the above problem could be GTK3 related, fixing this in the GTK3 support would be better than running with GTK2 support.

Comment: Yes indeed the problem is with GTK3 i ran SWT_GTK3=0 then started STS and UI is back to original with icons :-)

Comment: Glad to hear that switching to GTK2 support solved the issue, but I would still recommend to report this to Eclipse as an issue with the GTK3 support. The GTK2 support is no longer maintained and will cause issues in the future, so solving the underlying issue in the GTK3 support would make a lot of sense.

Comment: Was a bug ever filed against this? as I get the exact same issue...

Comment: I am not yet authorized to file this bug. Request anyone who can file this issue.